# Do I need a visa for travelling to France/Italy/Greece with Blue card issued in Germany and Indian passport?

Tags: visas, germany, europe, india, blue-card

I recently moved to Germany from India and have received a blue card permit (AUFENTHALTSTITEL, BLAUE KARTE EU) this month. It is valid till 2025. My passport is still Indian.

I am planning to visit France, Italy or Greece on a vacation for 4-5 days in the next month.

Do I need a visa for travelling to any of these countries?

Comment: You need no visa, or rather you *have* a German visa which allows you to visit other Schengen states for 90 out of 180 days. However, these days Corona rules apply.

Comment: @o.m. It's not a visa, it's a residence permit.

Comment: @Relaxed, in Germany they're both *Aufenthaltstitel*. §4 AufenthG.

Comment: @o.m. Other countries have similar concepts, the word is also used in the German version of the Schengen Borders Code. The word used in the English version of the Schengen Borders Code is “residence permit”.  Either way, the word “visa” is still improper, it's only one type of *Aufenthaltstitel.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a visa to enter another Schengen country, including all those listed, whether directly from Germany or from anywhere else in the world.

Answer (score -2):

A residence permit issued by a Schengen Country ('uniform format residence permits', in most cases a **residence permit** card) is considered to be a **visa replacement** for 3rd country nationals that normally require a C-Visa (Schengen Visa) for the Schengen Area.

Together with your passport short term visits, based on the 90/180 rule, to other Schengen Countries are possible.

The **residence permit** card alone is **not** a valid travel document.

It explains the reason why no entry stamp is in your passport for this period, since there are no immigration controls between the Schengen Countries (and thus no stamp is available).

Comment: You recently commented that “visa” was indeed spelled “visa”, not ”VISA” so why do you insist on writing “Visa”? The hyphen in “C-Visa” also makes no sense in English, incidentally.

Comment: @Relaxed [Hyphen Usage—Rules and Examples | Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen/): *When you connect words with the hyphen, you make it clear to readers **that the words work together as a unit of meaning**.* Since the combination denotes a **specific** type of visa, the usage of a hyphen does sense in English (, incidentally). As to the capital 'V', that is more out of habit, since the main language I write in nouns are always capitalized.

Comment: I don't know if you are quoting it disingenuously or out of ignorance but that quote is from a section titled “Two-Word Adjectives Before Nouns”. That is in fact a common and perfectly proper use of hyphens in English. For example you would write “a C-visa application” but “I applied for a C visa”. It's exactly the point I was making. I also know nouns are capitalised in German but now that you have been made aware of your mistake in English, feel free to correct it in your answer (that's what the edit button is for).